# Where is "Northwest" in The Dusty Path?

Tags: a-dark-room

In one question I saw, it says the compass points Northwest in the Dusty Path. I looked for an arrow or some form of marking for Northwest in the map, but I couldn't find anything. How do you know where Northwest is then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple actually. Up is North, right is East, down is South and left is West.

Just imagine that you are holding a compass against your screen, with the North facing up.

Comment: So its like in a normal map then.

Comment: Yea, it's like a normal map.